# Passing reference in c?

Tags: c

I was just wondering if someone could answer this review question I have for an upcoming exam. Unfortunately I do not have an answer key to double check and I wanted to be sure my answer was correct. Here is the question:

Which of the following correctly passes the reference to the variable `int max` to the function `f`?

```
a) f(max);
b) f(*max);
c) f(&max);
d) f(ref_max);
e) None of the above
```

My best guess would be c. Unless I'm completely wrong, I'm sure a, d, e are not right and it's not asking me to dereference anything like choice b. I'm sorry if I broke any posting rules with this website and I know its probably an easy question for most of you.

Comment: Can you try running the code yourself? (My vote: "c")

Comment: C calls functions by value

Comment: I suspect the person that created the question expects you to answer *c*, but the correct answer would be *e* since C does not have true pass by reference. In *c* you're calling `f` with a pointer to the address of `max`. The pointer is itself being passed by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"e) None of the above"

C does not have the ability to pass an `int` by reference.

The closest other candidate is "c) f(&max);".  In this case, the parameter passed to `f` is not `max`, but the address of `max`.  A *copy* of the address of `max` is received by `f(int *x)`.  It gets close to "pass by reference" for `max`, but it is a "pass by value" of the address of `max`.

```
int max;
void f(int *x);
f(&max);
```